# The color of his eyes is blue vs. The color of his eyes are blue

Tags: grammar, british-english, subject-or-object

So my younger brother came to me with a problem the other day. His 'the color of his eyes are blue' was corrected to 'the color of his eyes is blue'. I think this is the  teacher's error at play here, but I don't want to confront him without making sure. Which is the correct answer? And why? Any pointers is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: here we are putting the form of 'be' for color not eyes, so "... color of his eyes is blue.." is proper.

Answer (score 2):

Well, since the subject of the sentence is the word "color" and it is a singular noun, the verb should be conjugated in singular as well, hence it is "is".
Your doubt may arise from the fact that the subject seems to be "his eyes", but this is not true. It is instead part of the complement "of his eyes", of the subject.

Comment: To expand on this, you could also say, "The colours of his eyes are blue and green." (Either one is blue and the other is green, or they are both a mix of blue and green.) In this case, the plural *colours* is used, so the plural *are* is used.